# Eclipse: how to traverse all files in some folder

Tags: eclipse

I do have some org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder
I need to traverse all files in this folder. (I also need to do some SAX things for each file, but I don't want to load EMF model, because it's too slow)

What is the best way to get the list of all files in this folder and subfolders?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [IFolder.members()](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer.html#members()) recursively to traverse the directory. (I am a bit confused, why did you mention EMF?)